# JavaScript function that finds all the dynamic parameters and their corresponding columns in an SQL query

Tags: javascript, regex, postgresql

I'm trying to write a regex to find all the **dynamic parameters** and their corresponding columns in an SQL query.

**dynamic parameter:** every not reserved word in PostgreSQL that starts with a `$` sign inside an sql query.

i.e

```
'SELECT * from Students where grade > $g1 and grade < $g2  and grade < $g3' --> should return dynamic values as keys, and column names as array of values ---> {$g1:grade,$g2:grade,$g3:grade}

'SELECT * from Students where age > $g1 and grade < $g1' ----> {$g1:[grade,age]} we can assume that age and grade must have the column type.
```

dynamic parameters can occur either from left side of operator or right side of it. but they will always come with some SQL Comparison Operators i.e ( > , < , >= ,<>) OR inside `IN` clause.

i.e

1. `column_name SQL Comparison Operators $dynamic_Param`
2. `$dynamic_Param SQL Comparison Operators column_name`
3. `column_name IN ($dynamic_Param, $dynamic_Param)`

```
function findParamColumn(query, param) {
  const regex = new RegExp(`\\b${param}\\b\\s*(?:[+\\-*/<=>!]+|IN)\\s*(?:\\$\\w+|\\d+)`, 'gi');
  const matches = query.match(regex) || [];

  const columnRegex = /\b[a-z_]+\b/gi;
  return matches.map(match => match.match(columnRegex)[0]);
}
```

```
function findParamsColumns(query) {
  const paramRegex = /\$\w+/g;
  const params = query.match(paramRegex) || [];

  const paramsColumns = {};
  for (const param of params) {
    const column = findParamColumn(query, param);
    paramsColumns[column] = param;
  }
  return paramsColumns;
}
```

Here is what I've done so far the but `findParamColumn` doesn't return the expected result.

any suggestions and modfications to the regex?

Comment: I'm not sure about the implementation as a javascript function, but how about this solution?
https://regex101.com/r/73O0fA/1

It answers your three use cases, separating the output to separate capture group for the column and the parameter.

Comment: it looks like it's the direction for the solution would it be possible to ignore the white spaces between the column_name operator paramaeter_name---> i.e age>$g1, and age >   $a2(3 white spaces in this example)

Comment: "*`findParamColumn` doesn't return the expected result.*" - please post a [mcve] showing how you call `findParamsColumns` and what the expected result is

Comment: @AmitayTsinis I made all the whitespaces optional and added another test:
https://regex101.com/r/D9824b/1

Comment: @O-O-O thanks a lot for the help ,```Bergi``` answer was accepted and works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get some results from your function, you'd need to

- flip `param` and `column` in the `paramsColumns` object construction
- flip the order of operands in the `regex` you are building - in your examples the column name comes first and the parameter last
- escape the `$` sign of the `param` in your `regex` construction

With these minimal changes, you'd get the desired result:

```js
for (const test of [
  'SELECT * from Students where grade > $g1 and grade < $g2  and grade < $g3', // {$g1:grade,$g2:grade,$g3:grade}
  'SELECT * from Students where age > $g1 and grade < $g1', // {$g1:[grade,age]}
]) {
  console.log(test);
  console.log(findParamsColumns(test));
}

function findParamColumn(query, param) {
  const regex = new RegExp(`(?:\\w+|\\d+)\\s*(?:[+\\-*/<=>!]+|IN)\\s*\\${param}`, 'gi');
  const matches = query.match(regex) || [];

  const columnRegex = /\b[a-z_]+\b/gi;
  return matches.map(match => match.match(columnRegex)[0]);
}

function findParamsColumns(query) {
  const paramRegex = /\$\w+/g;
  const params = query.match(paramRegex) || [];

  const paramsColumns = {};
  for (const param of params) {
    const column = findParamColumn(query, param);
    paramsColumns[param] = column;
  }
  return paramsColumns;
}
```

However, this is not a good approach. There's no reason to use three different regular expressions, or even to construct them dynamically. And it handles only one of the patterns that you want to match. Instead, I would recommend

```js
for (const test of [
  'SELECT * from Students where grade > $g1 and grade < $g2  and grade < $g3', // {$g1:grade,$g2:grade,$g3:grade}
  'SELECT * from Students where age > $g1 and grade < $g1', // {$g1:[grade,age]}
  'SELECT * from Students where $g1 < age and $g2 <= grade', // {$g1:[age], $g2:[grade]}
  'SELECT * from Students where name IN ($a, $b, $c)', // 
]) {
  console.log(test);
  console.log(findParamsColumns(test));
}

function findParamsColumns(query) {
  const paramsColumns = {};
  for (const match of query.matchAll(/(\w+)\s*(?:[*\/<=>!+-]+)\s*(\$\w+)/gi)) {
    const column = match[1], param = match[2];
    (paramsColumns[param] ??= []).push(column);
  }
  for (const match of query.matchAll(/(\$\w+)\s*(?:[*\/<=>!+-]+)\s*(\w+)/gi)) {
    const param = match[1], column = match[2];
    (paramsColumns[param] ??= []).push(column);
  }
  for (const match of query.matchAll(/(\w+)\s*IN\s*\(([^)]+)\)/gi)) {
    const column = match[1], params = match[2].match(/\$\w+/g);
    for (const param of params) {
      (paramsColumns[param] ??= []).push(column);
    }
  }
  return paramsColumns;
}
```

Comment: would it be possible to include matching a '.' inside a column name, not in the dynamic parameter? for example  'SELECT * from Students as s, where s.grade > $g1' the result ```${g1:[s.grade]}```

Comment: Sure, just change the `\w+` for the column names into `\w+(\.\w+)?` or whatever you desire. (Notice these still don't exactly follow the SQL standard)

Comment: ```(Notice these still don't exactly follow the SQL standard)``` could you please elaborate?
where does the example query doesn't follow the standards?

Comment: The SQL standard doesn't allow identifiers to begin with a digit but `\w+` does, the SQL standard allows quoting identifiers, and surely some extra non-ASCII characters. Check the documentation of your RDMS dialect for the exact grammar. But afaict, you want a quick'n'dirty solution, not write an SQL parser :-)

Comment: we will leave the SQL parser solution to the PostgreSQL team :-), thanks a lot.

Comment: Tried to change ```\w+``` to ```\w+(\.\w+)?``` but I don't get the previous results, looks like it doesn't work, tried to modify it but didn't manage.

```/(\w+)\s*(?:[*/<=>!+-]+)\s*(\$\w+)/gi```-->/w+(\.\w+)?\s*(?:[*/<=>!+-]+)\s*(\$\w+)/gi

Comment: You missed the backslash and removed the capturing group, it needs to be `/(\w(?:\.\w+)?)\s*…`